# how long will a developer account remain acitive?

Tags: sandbox, developer

how long will a developer account remain active? if I keep logging in every week will it ever be deleted? How does this differ from a sandbox account or a training org?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forever. No need to keep logging in.

Comment: Do people in small companies just use a developer account instead of using a paid account? Seems like it might be an area that people could abuse. Although I doubt SFDC cares about account of that size.

Comment: Small data storage and the terms of use prevent that. If Salesforce finds you using the org for production data, they can delete the org.

Comment: Is that common? Do you know of any actual occurrences of this? I'm just curious, I'm going through my dev certs right now so I'm interested in knowing more about the inner politics of SFDC.

Comment: It has nothing to do with politics and everything to do with legality. Don't try it. Period. Besides, with only two users and almost zero storage, you couldn't do much with it anyway.